# How to draw multiple stacked area charts in a grid using Plotly (python)?

Tags: python, plotly

I can draw multiple bar charts in a grid using subplots. But, I can't do the same for a stacked area chart. I think this has something to do with the fact that each layer in a stackedArea chart is itself a Scatter chart and it looks like there is no way to create plots out groups of Scatter charts.

Any pointers would be much appreciated!